# How to have a discord bot resend a message until I tell it to stop?

Tags: python, discord, bots

For example, I would type "!hello", and the bot would continue to message hello back until I write something like "!stop".

Answer (score 1):

```
stop_var = False

@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    global stop_var
    stop_var = True

@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    global stop_var
    stop_var = False
    while True:
        await ctx.send("Hello")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if stop_var:
            break
```

Pretty sure this will work

Btw you will probably get ratelimited if you do this so maybe make the sleep time like 5 seconds or longer idk